# Upper bounds for the dimension of a binary cyclic code

Tags: linear-algebra, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, finite-fields, coding-theory

Let $\mathbb{F}_2 = \{0,1\}$ denote the field with two elements. Consider a binary $N$-tuple $a = a_0 a_1 \ldots a_{N-1}$, of elements $a_i \in \mathbb{F}_2$. The cyclic code $C_a$ corresponding to $a$ is the vector space, over $\mathbb{F}_2$, which is spanned by the cyclic shifts of $a$. That is, 
$$
C_a = Span\{ (a_0, a_1, \ldots, a_{N-1}), \ (a_{N-1}, a_0, \ldots, a_{N-2}), \ 
\ldots, \ (a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_0)   \}.
$$ 
The dimension of $C_a$ is then the rank of the $N \times N$ matrix whose rows are the tuples above. I'm interested in knowing whether, in a general setting, one may be able to obtain upper bounds for the rank given certain knowledge of the tuples. For instance, if you know that the sequence $a$ has certain amount of runs of $0$'s (or 1's), and how long these are, could one possibly give an upper bound based on this? What pieces of information may be useful to obtain a good upper bound? Thanks!

Comment: Could you please explain how can you obtain this bound? There's a strange implication: Suppose a = 00...01*...*100...0, is the sequence with the largest run of zeros being the run at the beginning + the run at the end (the sequence is cyclic so you add these two). Note the polynomial of the sequence has degree the index, R,  of the right-most "1", and the multiplicity of its root 0 is the index, L, of the left-most "1", in the sequence. Then the number of its non-zero roots is R - L. Thus the nullity of the corresponding matrix is at most R - L. Hence its rank is at least N - (R - L).

Comment: Your bound then implies that N - (R - L) <= N - r, i.e., r <= R - L. But surely this is impossible in general, for instance take a = 000000110000000000.

Comment: Sorry, I was not paying attention to the details. The correct version of my comment is as follows. As pointed out in Jyrki's answer, the dimension of the cyclic code is exactly $n-\deg\gcd(a(x),x^n-1)=n-\deg \gcd(x^ia(x),x^n-1)$. If the longest run of $0$s in $a(x)$ has length $s$, then $\deg\gcd(a(x),x^n-1)\leq n-s-1$ and consequently, the dimension is $\geq s+1$. This bound is tight if $a(x)$ is an _m_-sequence of length $2^{s+1}-1$. Of course, you are looking for an upper bound on the dimension, and so all this is not germane to the question. I have deleted my previous (incorrect) comment.

Answer (score 1):

A polynomial time algorithm for calculating the rank of $C_a$ is described in most books on algebraic coding theory. All you need to do is to calculate the gcd of $x^N-1$ and $a(x):=\sum_ia_ix^i$. If that gcd is of degree $k$, then $\dim C_a=N-k$.

Cyclicity of a linear code is a very strong property severely constraining the number of codes you can get. It makes the algebra much more interesting - for example by giving us the toolbox of (discrete) Fourier analysis to play with. But it also means that nearly all kind of randomizing tends to trivialize the code, as those usually don't mesh with the algebra of cyclicity. For example, changing a single one of the coefficients $a_i$ often means that the above gcd becomes trivial, and your code becomes useless.

Therefore any general bound based on lengths of runs is unlikely to exist, because changing one of the run lengths by one leads to unpredictable changes in the code.

To get an idea of the algebraic/number theoretic flavor of this phenomenon consider the following toy example. Let $N=24$. If you use $a=1111\,1111\,0000\,0000\,0000\,0000$, a run of eight 1s followed by sixteen 0s, then the above gcd is of degree $7$, and the code has rank $17$. Basically because $8\mid 24$. But if you use a run of seven 1s followed by seventeen 0s, the gcd becomes trivial and the cyclic shifts of $a$ span all of $\Bbb{F}_2^{24}$. And divisibility properties like this only give us full information when there is a single run of 1s.

---

Proving the result in the first paragraph. When looking at cyclic codes of length $N$ we work with the ring $R=\Bbb{F}_2[x]/\langle x^N-1\rangle$. When we turn all the words of the code $C_a$ into polynomials they form a set $C$ that is 1) closed under addition (because $C_a$ is linear), and 2) closed under multiplication by $x$ (because $C_a$ is cyclic). Therefore $C$ is an ideal of $R$. Let $I$ be the ideal of $\Bbb{F}_2[x]$ consisting of all the polynomial with their image in the ideal $C$. By basic properties of the polynomial ring the ideal $I$ is generated by its lowest degree non-zero element, $g(x)$. Because $C$ is spanned by the remainders of $x^ka(x)$ modulo $x^N-1$ ($k$ = the number of shifts), it follows that $g(x)=\gcd(a(x),x^N-1)$.

The space $C$ is then spanned by those polynomials $x^ig(x)$ that have degrees $<N$. If $k=\deg g(x)$, then the choices for $i$ are $0,1,\ldots,N-1-k$, and there are clearly $N-k$ of them.

Comment: If you haven't seen a proof of the algorithm in the first paragraph, just ask. I can elaborate easily.

Comment: Thank you for the insight. Is this the Berlekamp-Massey algorithm you refer to?

Here I explain the sequence $a$ I'm looking at, for which I'd like to obtain a reasonable upper bound for the rank.

Comment: No. It's not Berlekamp-Massey. Whoever first thought about cyclic codes using algebra of polynomials came up with it. My guesses would be either Skip Mattson or Gus Solomon, but I may be wrong about that.

Comment: Would you have some idea of how to go about it if one wishes to obtain a good upper bound for the rank here?

Comment: That. Is an interesting example! Too late here for me to now figure out what happens. It will have to wait :-(

Comment: :) have a good rest